# Prove that the result of any nested composition of morphisms is independent of the placement of paranthesis.

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory

[image]

I did my best to create my own proof, but reading it over it feels like I'm missing something. I just wanted to see if it looks alright to others.

***Proof:*** Let $\textbf{C}$ be a category and $f_i \in \text{Hom}_\textbf{C}(A_i, A_{i+1})$ be a morphism, where $A_j$ is an object of $\textbf{C}$ for $1 \leq j \leq n+1$.

Since $n=1$ and $n=2$ are trivial, we show the case for $n=3$:

$f_3f_2f_1=(f_3(f_2f_1))=((f_3f_2)f_1)$ by associativity in $\textbf{C}$.

For $n=4$, the $n=3$ case is included within so the result can be substituted:

$f_4f_3f_2f_1=(f_4(f_3f_2f_1))=(f_4((f_3f_2)f_1))$

then by shifting each parenthesis of the form $w(uv) \to (wu)v$, we obtain

$(f_4((f_3f_2)f_1)) = ((f_4(f_3f_2))f_1) = (((f_4f_3)f_2)f_1)$

as needed. Assume this holds for $f_nf_{(n-1)} \dots f_2 f_1$. For $f_{n+1}f_{n} \dots f_2 f_1$ we have

$f_{n+1}f_{n} \dots f_2 f_1 = (f_{n+1}(f_{n} f_{(n-1)} \dots f_2 f_1) = (f_{n+1}((\dots((f_{n} f_{(n-1)})f_{(n-2)}) \dots ) \dots f_2 ) f_1))$

again proceeding to shift every parentheses of the form $w(uv) \to (wu)v$, we obtain

$$((\dots((f_{(n+1)} f_{n})f_{(n-1)}) \dots ) \dots f_2 ) f_1)$$

as required.

Comment: Your example for $n=4$ has not shown that $(f_4 f_3)(f_2 f_1)$ is equal to the other placements of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

What you're "really" doing induction over is full binary trees representing different placements of parentheses.  The suggested induction over $n$ isn't an induction over the length of the sequence of arrows but the number of leaves in the full binary tree. There are [many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) full binary trees with $n$ leaves, and you need to prove that all of them can be reassociated into each other.

Let's instead do a *structural* induction over full binary trees. The theorem to prove is given an arbitrary full binary tree, it can be reassociated to a totally left associated tree.

> The base case is a leaf and that's trivially left associated. The
>  inductive case says given a branching node whose two subtrees can be
>  reassociated into totally left associated trees, then we can
>  reassociate this tree into a totally left associated tree. Call the
>  totally left associated left and right subtrees $L$ and $R$ respectively, we
>  have $(LR)$ and we want to show that it can be reassociated into a
>  totally left associated tree. To prove *this*, we do an induction on
>  the number of leaves in $R$. For the base case, $R = r_1$, we have
>  $(Lr_1)$ which is totally left associated. In the inductive case we
>  have $R = (R_nr_{n+1})$ and thus $(L(R_nr_{n+1}))$. We reassociate
>  that to $((LR_n)r_{n+1})$ and then use the inductive hypothesis on
>  $R_n$ to produce a totally left associated tree $L'$ whence
>  $(L'r_{n+1})$ is then totally left associated and we're done.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/01a49db3d914a934469d292988210590) is a complete formal proof in Agda following the above.